# Remove Unicode characters while querying in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, unicode, hive

I want to clean the unicode the data from the Hive table. The following is the data,

```
select ('http://10.0.0.1/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½aï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kn:4ï¿½+9xï¿½2cï¿½ï¿½mï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½')
```

My required output is to find if there are any unicode characters in my column and to remove it. The output here should be,

```
http://10.0.0.1/
```

or completely null. Either of them is fine. If a row contains any unicode character, it is fine to make it null completely.

The following are my tryings,

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE('http://10.0.0.1/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½aï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kn:4ï¿½+9xï¿½2cï¿½ï¿½mï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½', '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}', '')
```

and

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE('http://10.0.0.1/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½aï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kn:4ï¿½+9xï¿½2cï¿½ï¿½mï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½', '[||chr(128)||'-'||chr(255)||]', '')

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [40000 : 42000] Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:193 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ) near ')' in function specification 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.220 
 
STATEMENT 1: SELECT Statement failed.
```

Can somebody help me in cleaning these in my table?

Places where is is working,

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('"http://r.rxthdr.com/w?i=sï¿½Fï¿½""ï¿½HY|ï¿½Kï¿½>ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½W8ë¤’ï¿½O0ï¿½Qï¿½Dï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½Vc~ï¿½j[Qï¿½ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½{uï¿½Beï¿½S>nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Òï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½F9ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Cï¿½iï¿½ï¿½8:Ú”ï¿½_@ÄªOï¿½ï¿½K?ï¿½Ä’cï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½=ï¿½ï¿½v[ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½$%ï¿½ï¿½:ï¿½aï¿½40Ý©ï¿½&Oï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½ï¿½""ï¿½0ï¿½a<xï¿½ï¿½TcXï¿½ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½ï¿½TNï¿½}ï¿½xï¿½oï¿½ï¿½UY$Kï¿½Iï¿½Õ•""ï¿½ï¿½(+ï¿½Mï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Eï¿½=Kï¿½Aï¿½Iï¿½Aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½q#lï¿½(ï¿½ytï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½h}ï¿½ï¿½~[ï¿½ï¿½YOAï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½=ïˆï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½. ï¿½Qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ø­;x=ï¿½sï¿½0:ï¿½', '(?s).*\\P{ASCII}.*', '')
```

Places where it is not working,

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE('c4k0j,}W""d+2|4y0hkCkRh+.{pq80{?X8O>b<:ph.3!{T', '(?s).*\\P{ASCII}.*', '')

 select REGEXP_REPLACE('z|""},}69]6N2|c_;5.su={IU+|8ubq1<r$!Xxy#?Bhkv20:jXNgRh+5fwj:ndfWBJ}e)>','(?s).*\\P{ASCII}.*', '')
```

The first one in the image has a unicode character. But while pasting it becomes a dot.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(YOUR_STRING_HERE, '\\P{ASCII}.*', '')
```

It will remove all the string up to its end from the first found non-ASCII char.

Hive regex supports Unicode property classes, and `\p{ASCII}` matches any ASCII char. The opposite Unicode property classes are formed by turning `p` to upper case. So, `\P{ASCII}` matches any char that is not ASCII. `.*` matches any 0+ chars as many as possible, as `*` is a *greedy* quantifier.

Note that `.` does not match line breaks by default. If you need to remove line breaks, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern:

```
'(?s)\\P{ASCII}.*'
```

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE('z|""},}69]6N2|c_;5.su={IU+|8ubq1<r$!Xxy#?Bhkv20:jXNgRh+5fwj:ndfWBJ}e)>', '(?s)\\P{ASCII}.*', '') he following doesn't work.. Can you help me in solving this?

Comment: There are few unicode values which are not shown up here. Can we do something like if there are any unicode, make the entire row null?

Comment: Yes, to remove the whole row add `.*` before `\P{ASCII}`: `'(?s).*\\P{ASCII}.*'`

Comment: @haimen Your update does not help much, as the pasted texts [seem to have no non-ASCII chars](https://regex101.com/r/yP5KBZ/1). Please paste the 2-3 char chunk with those strange chars into a [Unicode converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) green field and let me know the hex codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling URLs you may want to consider removing characters that are considered unsafe in context of URLs. Broadly speaking safe URL characters are:

> Standard (safe) characters:
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> a b c d e f g h I j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> Special characters:
>
> ```
> $ – _ . + ! * ‘ ( ) ,
> ```

*[original article](https://abramillar.com/2018/01/15/special-characters-short-words-urls/)*

In that situation, a more natural choice for me is using `regexp_extract` in the following manner:

```sql
regexp_extract(question,'[a-zA-Z0-9\$\–\_\.\+\!\*\‘\(\)]*', 0)
```